# Google Sheet Conditional Formatting highlight 2 columns if one column contain certain text of 5 columns

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

In Google Sheet, I want to **highlight only 2 columns out of 5 columns.**

5 columns here but I want to **[highlight only 'Name' and 'Weight' columns if a cell contain the word 'Smith'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JzwS.png)**

The outcome should be like [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYLDq.png).
I want to input more name and if the name contain the word 'Smith', I want it to be automatically highlighted for name and weight columns.

I tried to use conditional formatting in Google sheet, and I could highlight only the name column.
This is what I tried.

[image]

Outcome was this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula given by @nabais works.

In conditional formatting though one does not need to use the starting `IF` function.

***"Format cells if"* is how conditional formatting rules are formed by default** as noted in the [official help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413).

> 4. Create a rule.
>
> - Single color: Under "**Format cells if**," choose the condition that you want to trigger the rule. Under "Formatting style, choose what the
>   cell will look like when conditions are met.
> - Color scale: Under "Preview," select the color scale. Then, choose a minimum and maximum value, and an optional midpoint value. To choose
>   the value category, click the Down arrow Down Arrow.

So the following formula is all that is needed:
*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

```
=REGEXMATCH($G2, "Smith")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are not far, try the following formula in the conditional formatting:

`=IF(REGEXMATCH($C3, "Smith"), 1, 0)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```js
function highlight() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = ss.getRange('A1:E').getValues();
  for (i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var tf = ss.getRange("B" + i).createTextFinder('smith');
    tf.matchEntireCell(false);
    tf.matchCase(false);
    var result = tf.findNext();
    if (result !== null) {
      var range = result.getRow();
      ss.getRange('B' + range).setBackground('Yellow');
      ss.getRange('D' + range).setBackground('Yellow');
    }
  };
};
```